# Smartphone win Application 's combobox load problem 

Tags: .net, winforms, .net-3.5, combobox, smartphone

Am working on smartphone application. Here I have a combobox which loads when the value of another combo gets changed.

```
private void cmbTreatmentType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     MasterData lData = new MasterData();
     cmbTreatmentCategory.DataSource = lData.GetTreatmentCategories((int)cmbTreatmentType.SelectedValue);     
     cmbTreatmentCategory.DisplayMember = "Description";
     cmbTreatmentCategory.ValueMember = "ID";
}
```

When this form gets loaded

`(int)cmbTreatmentType.SelectedValue`

throws exception like

*Cannot unbox '((System.Windows.Forms.ListControl)(this.cmbTreatmentType)).SelectedValue' as a 'int'*

Provided that the DataSource of cmbTreatmentType is DataTable as syntex same above.

But if you check the value through Debuging it goes well and no exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The combo box `SelectedValue` cannot be unboxed to `int`. Please check what value are you trying to unbox: maybe `null` (as the data source is not set yet) ?